# Using List Comprehensions in Python to Create a 2D List Sorted by Predefined Values

Tags: python

I have a function `number_sort()` which needs to return a 2d list with 4 lists inside. Function needs to sort the numbers given by being between 0-12, 13-25, 26-38 and 39-51 which looks like:

**Given:** `[2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 13, 15, 51, 10, 15, 28]`

**Returned:** `[[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 10], [13, 15, 15], [28], [51]]`

I tried doing it with list comprehension.

```
def number_sort(cards: list):
    return [[item for item in cards if i * 13 <= item <= (i * 12 + 1)] for i in range(4)]
```

But when I give the exact example list given above, It returns `[[1], [13], [], []]`

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you want to groupby using 13 as floor divider:

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(l), key=lambda x: x//13)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 10], [13, 15, 15], [28], [51]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dynamic way you can write your code by setting constant `13`.

```py
def number_sort(cards: list):
    const = 13
    mx = round(max(data) / const)
    struct = [[] for i in range(mx)]
    for i in cards:
        struct[i // const].append(i)
    return struct
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a table of your bounds:

```
i | 13i | 12i+1
--+-----+------
0 |. 0  |   1
1 | 13  |  13
2 | 26  |  25
3 | 39  |  37
```

You can't have the upper bound increase in steps of 12 while the lower bound increases in steps of 13. The correct condition is

```
13 * i < item <= 13 * (i + 1)
```